# Ruby- prime number unique and duplicates

Tags: ruby, function, primes

I'm just learning Ruby :) and Im trying to create a simple prime-number program where *all* the primes of a number are printed.

I'm getting errors where the *prime and nonprime numbers are mixed up*
(ie: input of 9 will get you all nonprimes).

I'm sorry for such a beginner question - I'm struggling alot and need some help :)

```
puts "Enter a number please "
num = gets.chomp.to_i

i = 2
number = 2

while i < num
  if number % i == 0
    prime = false
  end
    i += 1
  end
  if prime == true
    puts "#{number} is prime"
  else
    puts "#{number} is not prime"
  end
  number += 1
end
```

Comment: _"all the primes of a number"_ – what do you mean by that? Can you give examples for some inputs and their expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while i < num
  if number % i == 0
    prime = false
  end
    i += 1
  end
  # ...
```

It looks like that first `end` is meant to be an `else`.

It's easier to catch these things when you simplify your code, e.g. this method reduces to this (although there are other issues with it):

```
i = 2
number = 2

while i < num
  (number % i).zero? ? prime = false : i += 1
  puts "#{number} is #{'not ' unless prime}prime"
  number += 1
end
```

Comment: _"It's easier to catch these things when you simplify your code"_ – the code that follows doesn't look simple to me. Shorter yes, but much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

End error is because of else

```
while i < num
  if number % i == 0
    prime = false
  else
    i += 1
  end
```

if you have a short If - neater is writing it like:

```
if-condition ? 1 : 0
```

and in your case while is.. not the nicest choice - you should use range

```
(1...3).map{|x|  puts(x) }
```

{} - allows multiline(with do end end)

this prints [1,2]

```
(1..3).map{|x| x*2 }
```

would be [2,4,9]

This should be enough hints of how to play around with your code without ruining the process.